# Execute multiple shell commands in Node.js

Tags: node.js, shell

I want to execute multiple Shell commands from a node.js application consecutively. In my case, `exec(command1 & command2)` does not work as it should. It works for simple commands like `ls` and `pwd`, but I need to start a server and then execute special commands on it and there, it only executes the very first command and nothing more. When I work on my command-line interface, I just type in one command after the other and I need a facility to execute them in the same manner, but automatically starting from a node.js application - and all of them in the same process!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `child_process` module to achieve that.

Here's an example code to demonstrate the usage

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

var task1 = child_process.exec('node --version', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});

var task2 = child_process.exec('npm --version', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had already tried child_process.exec, but in a bit different way. My problem hasn't been solved, but now I'm quite sure that its cause is on the server I want to access and not in node.js.